# Soccer SQL Query Home- and Roadteam Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In a soccer environment I want to display the current standings. Meaning: points and goals per team. The relevant tables look similar to the following (simplified).

#### Match Table

```
uid  (PK)      hometeamid      roadteamid
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Result Table

```
uid (PK)      hometeamscore   roadteamscore       resulttype (45min, 90min, ..)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Team Table

```
uid (PK)       name            shortname           icon
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I don't get my head around it, how to write the standings in one query. What I managed was to write a query, which returns the "homegames"-standings only. I guess that's the easy part. Anyway here is how it looks:

```
SELECT  ht.name, 
        Count(*) As matches,   
        SUM(res.hometeamscore) AS goals, 
        SUM(res.roadteamscore) AS opponentgoals, 
        SUM(res.hometeamscore - res.roadteamscore) AS goalDifference,         
        SUM(res.hometeamscore > res.roadteamscore) * 3 + SUM(res.hometeamscore = res.roadteamscore) As Points

FROM league_league l

JOIN league_gameday gd
     ON gd.leagueid = l.uid

JOIN league_match m
     ON m.gamedayid = gd.uid

JOIN league_result res
     ON res.matchid = m.uid 
     AND res.resulttype = 2

JOIN league_team ht
     ON m.hometeamid = ht.uid

Where l.uid = 1

Group By ht.uid

Order By points DESC, goalDifference DESC
```

Any idea how to modify this, that it will return home- and roadgames would be big time appreciated.

Many thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create views. If your data does not change often and you need performance, create one or more pre-computed tables.

Views in MySQL are juste pseudo-tables that are dynamically computed from a SELECT query. Using the SQL in your question, you can create a view of the teams results at home: `CREATE VIEW homegames AS SELECT ...`
Then do the same for road games. Then it will be easy to synthesize both views in a third one (you just need to sum up the columns).

Views have at least one flaw: they are slow. A view built on views is like using complex subqueries, and MySQL is quite bad at this. I don't think it's a problem for you as you're probably dealing with hundreds of games at most. But if you find these views to be too slow to query, and provided you don't use any kind of cache that could mitigate this, then use simple tables instead of views. Of course, you'll need to keep them in sync. You can `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT INTO homegames SELECT ...` each time you have a new game, or you can be smarter and just `UPDATE` the tables. Both are right, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not abstract this out into a stored procedure or stored function to call rather than constructing such a big-ass complicated query?

Comment: Ouch. Unfortunately I do not know that, yet. My MySql knowledge is still very basic - and I am aware, that I do need to make some progress there. Nevertheless, is your advice, that this request is too complicated for one query?

Comment: Evernoob, please don't post as an answer what is just a question or a comment.

Comment: I don't see how stored procedure could help here. Whether you write this query in a stored procedure or not, it's still the same. IMHO it's a good query, quite easy to read. MySQL's doc has a warning that performance can decrease if there are more than 6 joins in a query, but that's important for queries on millions of rows. Unless tests prove that this query is too slow, keep with it.